# Slowly reduce the number

Tags: java, javascript, math

I have a number that is being increased by an increment on each step. Let's assume that start number is `0` and increment is `100`.

On step `#5` and later I want to start decreasing the base increment (`100`). The increment should be decreased smoothly and at step `#10` it equals `0`.

Here is  a graph that basically explains what am I trying to do (y - increment, x - step).

[image]

Code representation:

```
// x - step
// y - increment

var value = 0;
for(var x = 0; x < 10; x++) {


    var y = 100;
    if(x > 5) {
       // y = ???
    } 
    value += y;

}
```

So the question is how to represent this? It would be also great to have an option to modify the smoothness of this arc.

Thank you!

Comment: Is that arc supposed to be a quarter circle?  Or some other shape?

Comment: i think cos and sin are your friends here

Comment: @DavidWallace the problem is that I don't know how to name it. The closer to step `#10`, the smaller should be increment, but at step `#10` it must be `0`.

Comment: No, @AntonD, not cos and sin, if it's a quarter circle.  Squares, square-roots, multiplication and subtraction.

Comment: Well, @Marvin3, there are lots of different types of shape that you can draw between two points.  A quarter circle is just one option.  It could be a parabola, for example, a sine curve, or a dozen other options.  You are asking for a mathematical formula for a shape, without telling us what the shape is.

Comment: @DavidWallace, thx, well, let's assume that it's quarter circle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you a perfect quarter cirle that starts at (5|100) and ends at (10|0).

```
if (x > 5) {
    y = 100 * Math.sqrt( 1 - Math.pow(((x - 5) / 5), 2) );
}
```

http://fooplot.com/plot/2i8hy2twl4

## Explanation (optional)

**Warning! May contain mathematics!**

Let's start with a simpler case, a quarter circle with a radius of 1 and its center is (0|0). We know that `x² + y² = r²`(Pythagorean theorem). x and r are known, so we can calculate y this way: `y = sqrt(r² - x²)`. Since our radius is always 1 and 1² is equal to 1, we can break it down to this:

```
y = sqrt(1 - x²)
```

The value of y ranges from 0 to 1. We want it to range from 0 to 100 though. To achieve this, we simply multiply the right side by 100.

```
y = 100 * sqrt(1 - x²)
    ^^^^^^
```

To shift the entire thing 5 to the right, we need to subtract 5 from x.

```
y = 100 * sqrt(1 - (x - 5)²)
                    ^^^^^
```

Also, we want to stretch it to the right, so that our quarter circle ranges from x = 5 to x = 10 and not to x = 6, so wie divide (x - 5) by 5.

```
y = 100 * sqrt(1 - ((x - 5) / 5)^2)
                           ^^^^
```

Everything to do now is to replace sqrt by Math.sqrt and ^2 by Math.pow to make it valid Javascript code.

```
y = 100 * Math.sqrt( 1 - Math.pow(((x - 5) / 5), 2) );
```

Answer (score 1):

If that curve is a quarter circle, then the equation that you want is

```
y = 20 * Math.sqrt(x * (10 - x));
```

If it's not a quarter circle, then it's anyone's guess.

Answer (score 1):

```
if (x<=5)
    y = 100;
else if (x>=10)
    y = 0;
else {
    double radius = 100;
    double offset = (x-5)*20;
    y = Math.sqrt(raidus*radius - offset*offset);
}
```

http://fooplot.com/plot/offuyxbfzu

Comment: This isn't _JavaScript_, but it looks right. Could be simplified, too. (`raidus*radius - offset*offset = -400x*x + 4000x = 400(10 - x)x = (20*20)(10-x)x`)

Comment: To be fair, the OP did tag it as both Java and JavaScript.  I took that to mean that the actual mathematics was more important than what language was used.